# :checked selector is not working with input[type=radio]

Tags: html, css

I have tried many times to customize the style of the radioboxes below but I fail , My HTML and CSS code included below .
Note: I have tried to use `+` instead of `~` in this line :

```
.accountcolormaindiv input[type=radio]:checked ~ .accountcolormaindiv label:before {
```

but the problem still found !

```css
.accountcolormaindiv input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

.accountcolormaindiv label {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
  border-radius: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  color: #FFF;
  position: relative;
}

.accountcolormaindiv input[type=radio]:checked~.accountcolormaindiv label:before {
  content: "✔";
  position: absolute;
  color: #FFF;
  left: 50%;
  top: 51%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -44%);
}
```

```html
<div class="accountcolormaindiv">
  <input type="radio" checked name="accountcolor" id="onecheckbox" value="one">
  <input type="radio" name="accountcolor" id="twocheckbox" value="two">
  <label for="onecheckbox" class="onecheckboxtwo checkboxtwo"></label>
  <label for="twocheckbox" class="twocheckboxtwo checkboxtwo"></label>
</div>
```

Thanks ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is wrong and the color of :before content is the same as background. See the changes I made on this pen: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MpmZRG)

```
.accountcolormaindiv input[type=radio] {
    display: none;
}

.accountcolormaindiv label {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
    border-radius: 200px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    color: #FFF;
    position: relative;
}

.accountcolormaindiv input[type=radio]:checked + label:before {
    content: "✔";
    position: absolute;
    color: black;
    left: 50%;
    top: 51%;
    transform: translate(-50% , -44%);
}
```

I have also updated HTML structure so that css adjacent selector will match the label next to it

```
<div class="accountcolormaindiv">
    <input type="radio" name="accountcolor" value="one">
    <label for="onecheckbox" class="onecheckboxtwo checkboxtwo"></label>
    <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="accountcolor" value="two">
    <label for="twocheckbox" class="twocheckboxtwo checkboxtwo"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: There is a curly brace missing in the last selector

Comment: Indeed, last selector had a missing curly brace. The checkmark is not rendered at the same position, try it yourself by changing the checked="checked" attribute

Comment: Yeah, that was a mistake in my thinking. I forgot that only one of the radiobuttons can be selected :)

Comment: Thanks alot guy :*